# How to know whether service is running using adb shell in android

Tags: android, adb

I want to know whether media player service (registers with media.player when device boots up) is running or not using adb shell. Is it possible?

I tried running ps command but no success.

Comment: if ps is not showing any information related to the media service, it means the process related to service is not started!(when device boots up)

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Try the command line

`adb shell service list`

I get a list of service names and their package names as well.

Comment: media.player: [android.media.IMediaPlayerService] is among the listed services on my device.

Comment: it seems it only shows the system service, rather than apps' service, right?

Comment: Can I kill them? the one of service list

Answer (score 102):

As mentioned already, `adb shell service list` will only list system services.

As explained in [Android Emulator: How can I get a list of services that are running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12157442/android-emulator-how-can-i-get-a-list-of-services-that-are-running), you can look for services created by apps by using

```
// List all services
adb shell dumpsys activity services

// List all services containing "myservice" in its name
adb shell dumpsys activity services myservice
```

If it returns something, it means the service is installed. To know if the service is currently started or stopped, look for `app=ProcessRecord(...)` or `app=null`  respectively.

You can also do it Linux style with a simple

```
ps | grep myservice
```

while inside of your shell.

Comment: If my application is a system application, will be it be displayed with "adb shell service list" command?

Comment: "adb shell dumpsys activity services myservice" worked like a charm.

Answer (score 28):

To simply check whether a specific service is running, use:

```
adb shell service check <service>
```

For example, `adb shell service check media.player` gives `Service media.player: found` if it's running and `Service media.player: not found` otherwise.

If you need more detail, try `dumpsys <service>`.  For example, `adb shell dumpsys media.player` returns information about `media.player`'s clients, open files, etc.

Finally, if you really need serious detail for debugging, try `adb shell dumpsys activity services` which shows what's going on from `ActivityManager`'s point of view.  This includes information about intents, create times, last activity time, bindings, etc., etc.  You can redirect the output if you want to store it for later viewing/searching.  It's typically rather lengthy.

Comment: But knowing exact package name of your app's services could be cumbersome :(  Can be used with | grep -i "myservice"

Comment: `adb shell service check <myservice>` doesn't seem to return the same information as `adb shell dumpsys activity services <myservice>` and then looking at `app=`. I'm not sure which is wrong, but the first seemed to indicate a certain service wasn't running, while the latter did.

Answer (score 5):

For Android 10, list **all currently running** services:

```
adb shell dumpsys activity services | grep "ServiceRecord" | awk '{print $4}' | sed 's/.$//' | sort
```

Answer (score 0):

To know whether an app process is running or not (background or foreground):

```
adb shell pidof <package.name>
```

It'll return empty string if process is not running else its pid.