# Android Emulator: How can I get a list of services that are running

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-service, monitoring, monitor

I have the **Android Emulator** running in my **Ubuntu VM** and just installed an apk file trough the console. The emulator and adb have many options to view what is going on on the device.
But how can I get a **list of services** that are currently running? I'm trying to find out if a specific app installes a notify service to view (unwanted) ads. I even know the services' name.

PS.: I'm an advanced beginner - but not advanced enough. So thanks for your help.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

You can get the list with the following command :

```
adb shell dumpsys activity services
```

Comment: putting that into a file with >> filename is exactly what I needed.

Comment: You can do `adb shell dumpsys activity services com.myservice` to filter the result. Look for `app=ProcessRecord(...)` or `app=null` to know if the service is currently started or stopped.

Answer (score 25):

If you just need a simple list without all the detail dumpsys generates, use:

```
adb shell service list
```

Comment: `service list` only shows system services that are running, not services created by applications.

Answer (score 1):

Logcat might help you out as well

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```bash
adb shell dumpsys | grep "DUMP OF SERVICE"
```

It should give you a list that looks like "DUMP OF SERVICE" followed by the name of the service.