# Send message to custom service via adb

Tags: android

I create simple android [application](https://gitlab.com/Gluttton/DummyAndroid) which contains one activity and service. The service is defined by `aidl` file and can receive calls from the activity via `Binder`. Everything works as expected.

Now I deploy the application on device (also I've tried an emulator) and I want to send message to the service via `adb`:

```
$ adb shell service call \
    com.example.gluttton.dummyandroid/.DummyService 0 STR "Bingo!"
```

and got message that such service doesn't exist:

> service: Service com.example.gluttton.dummyandroid/.DummyService does
>   not exist

I try to check is my service launched:

```
$ adb shell service list
```

or

```
$ adb shell service check com.example.gluttton.dummyandroid/.DummyService
```

and got similar result.

But at the same time I cat see my service using `dumpsys`:

```
$ adb shell dumpsys activity services Dummy
ACTIVITY MANAGER SERVICES (dumpsys activity services)
  User 0 active services:
  * ServiceRecord{a1627b5 u0 com.example.gluttton.dummyandroid/.DummyService}
    intent={act=android.intent.action.MAIN     cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER]     cmp=com.example.gluttton.dummyandroid/.DummyService}
    packageName=com.example.gluttton.dummyandroid
    processName=com.example.gluttton.dummyandroid
    baseDir=/data/app/com.example.gluttton.dummyandroid-1/base.apk
    dataDir=/data/data/com.example.gluttton.dummyandroid
    app=ProcessRecord{114da04c 20168:com.example.gluttton.dummyandroid/u0a126}
    createTime=-21m40s817ms startingBgTimeout=--
    lastActivity=-21m40s816ms restartTime=-21m40s816ms createdFromFg=true
    startRequested=true delayedStop=false stopIfKilled=false callStart=true lastStartId=1
```

Also I can start my service:

```
$ adb shell am startservice com.example.gluttton.dummyandroid/.DummyService
Starting service: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.example.gluttton.dummyandroid/.DummyService }
```

and stop it:

```
$ adb shell am stopservice com.example.gluttton.dummyandroid/.DummyService
Stopping service: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.example.gluttton.dummyandroid/.DummyService }
Service stopped
```

So my question is where is my mistake and how to send message to my service via `adb`?

Comment: seems its for system services only: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12157442/android-emulator-how-can-i-get-a-list-of-services-that-are-running#comment63723794_24208845, i couldnt find my service as well using `service list`

Comment: and if `adb shell am startservice` works then use it to pass the message to your service

Comment: @pskink, can you show how to pass the message using `startservice`?

Answer (score 1):

I think system/bin/service is only for working with android system services.  If you do a `adb -s emulator-5554 shell service list` for example you will see only a list of services such as

```
Found 100 services:
0   carrier_config: [com.android.internal.telephony.ICarrierConfigLoader]
1   phone: [com.android.internal.telephony.ITelephony]
2   isms: [com.android.internal.telephony.ISms]
3   iphonesubinfo: [com.android.internal.telephony.IPhoneSubInfo]
```

If you wish to send a message to your service you can do so via

```
adb shell am startservice [options] intent
```

Start the Service specified by intent.
See the Specification for intent arguments.

Options are:

--user user_id | current: Specify which user to run as; if not specified, then run as the current user.

see this [link](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb.html#IntentSpec) for how to set up the intent as an argument

Answer (score 0):

adb shell am start-foreground-service --user 0 -n com.varun.services/.wifiservice --ei "op" 1

there is a service inside the app wifiservice which will take input like 1 and then perform the operations by verifying the data

Service code is below

[image]

Might be this will helpful