# How to use Android Settings App's SettingsDumpService.dump() method

Tags: android, android-source

I am debugging an Android issue related to a data usage collection. My app is giving a different value than the one reported in the Android default settings application. For example:

[image: screenshot of data usage app]

While investigating I found the source code for [NetworkStatsService](http://androidxref.com/7.1.1_r6/xref/frameworks/base/services/core/java/com/android/server/net/NetworkStatsService.java#1241) which allows me to use `adb shell dumpsys netstats --full` to call its dump() method.

I also found the source code for [SettingsDumpService](http://androidxref.com/7.1.1_r6/xref/packages/apps/Settings/src/com/android/settings/SettingsDumpService.java) but don't see a way to call it from dumpsys. I've looked at the AndroidManifest.xml and the service is there:

```
<service
    android:name=".SettingsDumpService"
    android:exported="true"
    android:permission="android.permission.DUMP" />
```

I've used `adb shell am startservice com.android.settings/.SettingsDumpService` and it does seem to be running. But I don't seem to see the expected JSON output that the class would suggest anywhere.

I've also tried the "Take Debug Report" button in developer options, but I don't see the data I want anywhere in the output. Is this only for AOSP developers to use internally or is there a way for me to use it as well for debugging / investigation?

Answer (score 0):

[Android Emulator: How can I get a list of services that are running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12157442/android-emulator-how-can-i-get-a-list-of-services-that-are-running)

```
adb shell dumpsys activity service com.android.settings/.SettingsDumpService
```